# Extending ImmutableCollection

Tags: java, guava

I'd like to build a data model that conveys an iterator and a size, basically a read-only way of iterating a result set's elements.

I figured extending ImmutableCollection and implementing size() and iterator() was the best course of action, since this type adequately communicates my intent.

Unfortunately, ImmutableCollection has a package-private isPartialView.

My question: Why is isPartialView package-private, should it remain so, and if so, what is the best way to model my read-only collection?  Should I be creating a custom type with only the size() and iterator() methods (a SizedIterable)?  Are there other suggestions for this use case?

Comment: `Iterator` has `.remove`. For really read only IMO cleaner without > write everything on your own :)

Comment: You should extremely rarely **extend** collection classes. Instead you should **use** a collection, i.e. have a field of type ImmutableCollection inside your class, and delegate to it to implement `size()` and `iterator()`.

Comment: What's wrong with the existing `iterator()` and `size()` methods of `ImmutableCollection` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the operations in the [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) interface are considered optional. You could write your own implementation on that and throw the [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) for any action your implementation does not support. This would be a way to get around having to extend ImmutableCollection.

Subclassing [ImmutableCollection](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html) is probably not an option, as its documentation states the following:

> An immutable collection. Does not permit null elements.
>
> Note: Although this class is not final, it cannot be subclassed outside of this package as it has no public or protected constructors. Thus, instances of this type are guaranteed to be immutable.

Comment: Throwing an [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) is exactly what the `remove()` method of the [UnmodifiableIterator](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator.html) of [ImmutableCollection](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html) does.

Comment: It does - the explanation is mainly for the purposes of a custom Collection implementation that provides access through **only** a read only iterator. To your point, this is effectively what ImmutableCollection does.

Answer (score 4):

If it is not for performance issues, I would suggest you not try to create another Collection implementation. Read-only view of the collection is already provided by Java with the [`Collections.unmodifiableCollection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection%28java.util.Collection%29) method. If you want to stay with Guava, the `ImmutableList`, `ImmutableSet` and `ImmutableMap` are the classes you want to check out. To determine the size, you can use the [`Iterables.size()`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#size%28java.lang.Iterable%29) method from Guava.

If performance issues are present, then implementing the scheme with a `ForwardingCollection` and `UnmodifiableIterator` can be favorable. Example:

```
public static class CollectionWithUnmodifiableIterator<E> extends ForwardingCollection<E> {
    private final Collection<E> collection;
    public CollectionWithUnmodifiableIterator(final Collection<E> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }
    @Override
    protected Collection<E> delegate() {
        return collection;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return Iterators.unmodifiableIterator(super.iterator());
    }
}
```

Caching the size is also possible with the assumption that `addAll` and `removeAll` are not used or they are funneled through the `add` and `remove` calls where house keeping can be implemented based on the return value of the delegate method. But with other restrictions, e.g. if used only for lists, the `addAll` can be optimized.

Comment: Good catch, I was mistaken. ForwardingCollection is a better choice.